# Why is the bottom of my triangle vibrating?

Tags: animation, transforms

I am making a logo animation and I used keyframes to have the logo rotate. But whenever I play my animation on the 65th frame the bottom of the triangle starts to rotate

All I did was model a triangle and a star duplicate the star and parent them all so    I could rotate them together. My file down below so anyone can download then look at it.

[image]

Comment: BLENDER FILE:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4E3mYBGs" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4E3mYBGs/)

Comment: While I did find quite a few issues with the model you uploaded, I'm not sure what your question is. Where is this doughnut? Do you mean triangle? And do you want it to rotate? Your first sentence doesn't make grammatical sense.

Comment: I'm sorry for not editing my question I was in a hurry but I fixed it up and if  you still can't understand then just ask. THX

Comment: Can some one please help me I have a deadline at 9 PM

Comment: Try stretching out your triangle in the Y axis (at frame 0), you will be able to see the problem more clearly